# How to open an .exe file with -dev mode? (not the shortcut )

Tags: windows

I want to start Company of Heroes game with the `-dev` mode but not through the shortcut but using the original `.exe`. Is there any way to bind the `.exe` with this flag so that it opens all the time using that flag?

I tried everything I could from the Internet. I created a shortcut and made it run through a `.bat` file and then converted the `.bat` file to an `.exe` file but the file is not being detected as the original file.

I want to use the `.exe` file with the GameRanger software.

Comment: Is it not possible to point the GameRanger to the shortcut instead of the .exe?

Comment: I tried to point to a shortcut link but what it actually does is trace the path to the original file and starts from there and not from the shortcut. This is why I am not able to run in -dev mode.